# How to properly delete files in directory

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a code that will prompt if i want to delete files in the directory. The problem arises when the page refreshes, it will just delete the files without the prompt selection. I want to not delete the files even when the page refresh.

```
<script language="javascript">
function checkMe() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure")) {
        alert("Clicked Ok");
        <?php                   
            $files = glob('d:/pics/*'); // get all file names
            foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
            if(is_file($file))
            unlink($file); // delete file
            }
        ?>
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Clicked Cancel");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Here's the code for calling the function

```
<a href='index.php?main=add-doc' class='footer-img' onclick=\"return checkMe();\"><div class='record'><img src='images/download.png' style='position: relative; margin: auto;'/>Upload Record</div></a>
```

Comment: You'll need to look into AJAX. The code you have evaluates when the page renders, and not when the JS is run.

Answer (score 5):

You can't call php from javascript like that, php will always execute. The thing you want is Ajax.

file.php

```
$files = glob('d:/pics/*'); // get all file names

foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
    if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file); // delete file
}
```

and ajax in javascript, if you use jQuery it will be something like

```
function checkMe() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure")) {
        $.get('file.php', function() {
            //ignore
        });
    }
}
```

or you can put php in index.php file and check:

```
if (isset($_GET['main']) && $_GET['main'] == 'add-doc') {
    $files = glob('d:/pics/*'); // get all file names

    foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
        if(is_file($file))
            unlink($file); // delete file
    }
}
```

and in javascript put only confirm code:

```
function checkMe() {
    return confirm("Are you sure");
}
```

when you click the link and confirm return true the browser will follow the link and execute php code.

Comment: You should specify that you're using jQuery

Comment: @HamZa I did, I wrote "if you use jQuery it will be something like"

Comment: you wrote it *after* the edit, but since you improved your answer you got +1 from me :)

Comment: @HamZa after edit I wrote non-jquery solution, I wrote that I use jQuery from the begining.

Comment: ok doesn't really matter since it's there. Now hoping that the OP knows his way :p

Comment: @jcubic I think you have a point here, anyway i tried the jquery but nothing happens,(i included jquery lib), it did not delete the file in the folder, can you show me how to do it in ajax?

Comment: @user1999194 you need to put your php code in a file and call it using ajax (for instance using $.get), if you delete php code work it will be executed. you can display the stuff that your php code return (like errors) using `$.get('file.php', function(stuff) { console.log(stuff); });`